# Can't pull from repository - Git LFS object not found error

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a repository on Azure DevOps with my friends that we use to work on an Unreal Engine project (we push and pull with GitHub Desktop).
I can push and pull without any issue but if one of my friends tries to pull the newest version we get this error:
[Git LFS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoL6K.png)

I searched on google and as far as I understand the problem is that the repository on DevOps does not know about the files that cause the error?

I don't know how to resolve this and all I can find are commands using the git command prompt. (I don't understand what they do and I have never used the command prompt to do anything)

If anyone has a suggestion on how to handle this I'd be very greatful..

Comment: How does that question relate to the tags `github` and `github-for-windows`?

Comment: How is this question related to `unreal-engine5`? You seem to have a problem with git, not with Unreal.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this error by opening the project and saving every file in UE5 that came up in the git error. I then pushed these changes to the repository.